# How to check regex in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

Here I have phone numbers input field and I check this input field phoneNumber in if condition this phone number has only numbers or characters using regex, I check this regex using match but if condition gives error like match is not found, I want to check phoneNumber is only number in if condition how it is possible in angularjs ?

```
<div class="col-md-6">
   <small>Phone Number</small>
   <input type="text" name="phonenumber" placeholder="" ng-model="phoneNumber">
</div>

 if($scope.phoneNumber.match(/^[0-9]*$/)) {
    factories.error('This is valid phone number');
 } else {
    factories.error('Phone Number must be a number');
 }
```

Comment: If phoneNumber is undefined you'll hit an issue, you should use ngPattern on the model. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern

Comment: @kendavidson but ng-pattern not throws error, ng-pattern only if not valid phoneNumber then it is hide not throws error

Comment: Ah, my bad.  Then just check for phoneNumber being undefined before using it?  You can take a look at the ui-validate module as well, you can do both validate and use your .error() function in one shot.

Comment: Is this not any way to check validation for any country phone number in if condition in angularjs ?

Comment: I'm confused by your last comment.  There are really limited options a) ngPattern b) ui-validate module with function c) $watch phoneNumber d) some key/change event.  Regardless, you need to check phoneNumber for undefined before calling .match() on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ngPattern directive with a html form element;

Pattern for 10 digit phone number :

```
ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{10}$/"
```

see jsfiddle for an example.
https://jsfiddle.net/3p6daLbv/

You can also add dynamic errors using ng-messages and ng-message-exp directives;

```
      <div ng-messages="myForm.tel.$error" role="alert">
          <div ng-message-exp="['pattern']">
            Your number must be 10 numbers long.
          </div>
      </div>
```